# NodeJS serialport

Tags: node.js

Не могу работать с модулем serialport при дебаге выдаёт следующую ошибку

> C:\Users\Guru\Desktop\step motor project\electron-quick-start\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:121 Uncaught Error: The module '\?\C:\Users\Guru\Desktop\step motor project\electron-quick-start\node_modules@serialport\bindings\build\Release\bindings.node'
>   was compiled against a different Node.js version using
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. This version of Node.js requires
>   NODE_MODULE_VERSION 69. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
>   the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).

```
и т.д.
```

npm rebuild и npm install пробовал всё безрезультатно :(

Comment: Удали папку, а потом ставь. И ещё обновить попробуй.

Comment: проблема не в ноде, прост электрон нужно ребилдить. вот в этой репе https://github.com/nodebots/electron-serialport/blob/master/package.json видно как нужно